# Run node script with specific user

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

On my laptop, Ubuntu 14.04, I create a file `~/test.js` with the only content `console.log("Hi, this is Dog.")`. I run the script `node test.js` (node v6.9.5), and I get the desired output `Hi, this is Dog.`

Then I try to run the script as `www-data` user. So I run:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/node /home/me/test.js
```

and...

> Error: Cannot find module '/home/me/test.js'

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried with relative and absolute paths,

```
sudo -u www-data sh -c "/usr/bin/node /home/me/test.js"
```

changed the shell for `www-data` in `/etc/passwd` to `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`, and all the combinations of those ideas. Same error. Any idea?

Comment: Best remove the Ubuntu, Linux and Node.js tags as your question appears to be mostly about file permissions, which is not specific to any of these tags.

Comment: I feel like it might be something related to $PATH or $NODE_PATH or something like that. That's why I though those tags would make sense.

Comment: Ah ok, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that the permissions are set so that the www-date user does not have access to the file.

When logged in on the user account that created the test.js file, try something like:

```
chmod a+wx test.js
```

And then run your sudo command again.

Comment: It doesn't  work. I've also tried with `chmod 777 test.js`, and even `chown www-data.www-data test.js`. Same error.

Comment: Could you try something like `sudo "PATH=$PATH" -u www-data sh -c "/usr/bin/node /home/me/test.js"`?

Comment: Same error: `Error: Cannot find module '/home/me/test.js'`

Comment: Hmm.. maybe there is a similar command for Node_path, you could search for it. A path problem would indeed explain the error.

Comment: Just had this issue, thanks for giving the right path, however you do not need write permissions but read permissions, also you need execute (ls) permissions on the parent folders. `chmod a+rx test.js` `chmod a+x /home/me/`

Answer (score 0):

To run shell with specific user.
Here is a example that worked. User is me. Running this shell from root user.

```
HOME=/home/me sudo -u me bash -c '\
  cd /home/me/my_node_app_location
  export NVM_DIR="/home/me/.nvm"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
  [[ -r $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ]] && \. $NVM_DIR/bash_completion
  nvm use 11
  npm install
  node app.js
'
```

Remember, you have to load nvm for npm or node commands to work.

Answer (score 0):

The HOME folder is user specific. When you run `sudo` you effectively run the command as a your Admin user. That user has a different HOME directory than your regular user, and the `/home/me/test.js` doesn't exist in the HOME directory of the Admin user - thus the error.

A similar, very typical mistake is to run scripts that rely on ENV variables set for your normal user, but then run the script with `sudo`; the variables does not exist for the `sudo` user.